# LocalStorage and adding li to list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a small script that allows for a little notes section. This section would have an input box that allows for adding elements to the list; which will be saved in localStorage so they are not lost when I refresh or close the browser. The code I have is as follows (it's all done through JS even the html, but ignore that.)

```
var notes = [];
var listthings = "<h2 id=\"titlething\">Notes</h2>" +
                 "<ul id=\"listing\">" +
                 "</ul>"
                 "<input type=\"text\" name=\"item\" id=\"textfield\">" +
                 "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"submitthing\" value=\"Submit\">";

JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes')) || [].forEach( function (note) { 
    "<li id=\"listitem\">" + notes + "</li>";
    })

 $('#submitthing').click(function() {
     notes.push($('#textfield').val());
    });

localStorage.setItem('notes', JSON.stringify(notes));
```

Also, how would I go about appending the latest added li between the opening and closing tag? Obviously I'd usually do it using jQuery, but this is puzzling me a little.  However, only the 'Notes' loads at the top, any ideas?

Comment: Why are you using JSON? And, why would you "obviously" normally use JQuery?

Comment: It was reccomended to me from someone else. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's wrong. JSON is best used when moving data to/from a client and a server. Here, it gains you nothing.

Comment: I would 'obviously' use jQuery when appending elements to a list. $('').append(); for example.

Comment: I'm a bit confused...are you asking about how to use local storage, since you don't have any questions about that, or only about adding an `<li>` element to the list?  Also, regarding the insertion of the list item, are you looking for an answer on how to do it without jQuery?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to get it to work. If localStorage is the problem, which the user above telling me not to use said JSON says it is, then I guess I'm asking about that. I'm not too sure what the problem is, because as said, the 'Notes' loads, but then nothing else will load afterwords. I'm using `notes.push($('#textfield').val()` to add to the array, which should inturn list each element as a li. Or that's the plan anyway. No, I'm not looking for a way to do it without jQuery. I'm not sure how it would be achieved, like said above, I thought that the forEach would list each array item as a li.

Comment: @Ubuntuisconfusing JQuery is hardly necessary to append items to the DOM. Don't forget that the "J" in JQuery stands for JavaScript, there is nothing that JQuery can do that JavaScript can't since JQuery is just JavaScript that someone else has already written. In many cases, JQuery just confuses things. In others, it simplifies. Appending to the DOM is quite simple without JQuery. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is way off the mark. You don't need JSON at all (this just confuses things) and you don't need to manually create HTML.

Also, you can use an array to store the notes, but since localStorage is the storage area, so an array is redundant. Additionally, without using an array, you don't need JSON. The entire problem becomes much easier to solve.

Unfortunately, the following won't run here in this snippet editor, due to security issues, but it would do what you are asking. This fiddle shows it working: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqjwbn1r/14/

```js
// Upon the page being ready:
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   // Get a reference to the empty <ul> element on the page
   var list = document.getElementById("notes");

   // Loop through localStorage
   for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){

     // Make sure that we only read the notes from local storage
     if(localStorage.key(i).indexOf("note") !== -1){
      // For each item, create a new <li> element
       var item = document.createElement("li");
       // Populate the <li> with the contents of the current 
       // localStorage item's value
       item.textContent = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
       // Append the <li> to the page's <ul>
       list.appendChild(item);
     }
   }

   // Get references to the button and input
   var btn = document.getElementById("btnSave");
   var note = document.getElementById("txtNote");

   // Store a note count:
   var noteCount = 1;

   // When the button is clicked...
   btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
     // Get the value of the input
     var noteVal = note.value;

     // As long as the value isn't an empty string...
     if(noteVal.trim() !== ""){

       // Create the note in localStorage using the 
       // note counter so that each stored item gets
       // a unique key
       localStorage.setItem("note" + noteCount, noteVal);

       // Create a new <li>
       var lstItem = document.createElement("li");
       // Set the content of the <li>
       lstItem.textContent = noteVal;
       // Append the <li> to the <ul>
       list.appendChild(lstItem);
       // Bump up the note counter
       noteCount++;
     }
   });

});
```

```html
<input type=text id=txtNote><input type=button value=Save id=btnSave>
<ul id=notes></ul>
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. However, one note, I can't seem to clear things such as the browser I'm using from the localStorage despite running `localStorage.clear();` when running the script, certain things already load such as `browser=Firefox%204&manufacturer=Microsoft%20Corporation&device=Computer&os=Windows
0` Things such as my location also load? Any idea how this can be combated, or is this something I can't solve?

Comment: @Ubuntuisconfusing  In your browser's development tools (press F12 with the page open), navigate to the "Resources" or "Application" tab, where you should be able to see Local Storage as a category to look at. From there, you can see what's in storage and there should be an "X" button to clear out the currently selected local storage item. Don't forget to mark my post as the answer and upvote. Good luck!

Comment: @Ubuntuisconfusing There are going to be certain things added to local storage automatically depending on the page you are on. But, you can always check the local storage key name before taking it out and placing it back on your page. In my example, all the notes get stored with key names of `note` and a number, so you could just add another `if` statement that checks the key name before adding it to the bullets.

Comment: @Ubuntuisconfusing I've updated the code to show how you can exclude any localStorage keys that aren't your notes. Here's the updated fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqjwbn1r/14/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach it using jquery. but depens how complex this should be. this is just simple demo.

```
<input type="text" id="note" />
<button id="add">add note</button>

<ul id="notes"></ul>
```

javascript and jquery

```
function addNote(){
  var data = localStorage.getItem("notes")
  var notes = null;
  if(data != null)
  {
    notes = JSON.parse(data);
  }
  if(notes == null){
    notes = [];
  }
  notes.push($("#note").val());
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes));
  refreshNotes();
}
function refreshNotes(){
  var notesElement =$("#notes");
  notesElement.empty();
  var notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
  for(var i = 0; i< notes.length; i++){
    var note = notes[i];
    notesElement.append("<li>"+note+"</li>");
  }
}

$(function(){
  refreshNotes();

  $("#add").click(function(){
    addNote();
  });
})
```

example:
http://codepen.io/xszaboj/pen/dOXEey?editors=1010

Comment: So, in your solution, each time a single note is added, the entire set of notes (the array) is re-stringified and re-written to localStorage.

Comment: yeah as I said it is simple solution. If you need something more complex I would probably use some library that works well with localStorage so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The codepen linked doesn't load the items once the button clicked?

Comment: @xszaboj See my answer below. Much simpler...no JQuery...just plain JS. `localStorage` is an exceedingly simple API as it is, so I don't know why you'd be looking for another library to complicate things.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yeah I like it ;). Definitely better because you are using some kind of id. But as I said depends how complex this should be. Author of the question doesn't exactly state what he wants...

Comment: @xszaboj Also, I don't think your code works as you are trying to call `.append()` with a string and not a node. If you were determined to build the HTML up as strings, you'd use `.innerHTML` to inject it.